# CCsprite in circular shape rather than rectangular in cocos2d-x ios using c++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I make a sprite in cocos2dx c++ as.

```
CCSprite *mysprite=CCSprite::create("mysprite.png");
this->addchild(mysprite);
```

But as we all know this comes in a rectangular shape.If there a way to crop dynamically or to create a sprite in a circular shape knowing that the .png file is in rectangular shape.
Can we crop or create a sprite that take the .png and cut it as a circular shape.Are there any links or tutorials regarding this issue.
I am using cocos2dx 2.2 version
I am attaching two images of what i exactly want

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks
[image: rectange shape]
[image: after crop in circle]

Comment: Have you checked clipping node examples? There are many examples and you can use any shape.

Comment: can u please post a link.i ll be thankful

Comment: Check here : https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/tree/cocos2d-x-2.2.3/samples/Cpp/TestCpp/Classes/ClippingNodeTest You can find them in TestCpp project in samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (7-25-14)**

I can't really recommend CCMask anymore, considering that it is for v2.x and cocos2d-x is moving quickly with the v3.x branch. It's wisest to go with the built-in [ClippingNode](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2/d2/d06/classcocos2d_1_1_clipping_node.html).

---

**Original answer (4-19-2014)**

One option is [CCMask](https://github.com/syuhari/CCMask). Its interface is simpler than ClippingNode so you can get up and running faster.

From its readme:

```
// Create a mask and an object
CCSprite* mask = CCSprite::create("mask_circle.png");
CCSprite* object = CCSprite::create("HelloWorld.png");
object->setPosition(ccp(mask->getContentSize().width/2, mask->getContentSize().height/2));

// Create a masked image
CCMask* masked = CCMask::create(mask , object);
masked->setPosition(ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2));
this->addChild(masked);
```